# Select2 remove option not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-select2

I want to remove the select2 option and make it as the default input.
By using `$("#City").text('').trigger('change');` trigger change I can able to clear the select2 data instead of removing the total select2 dropdown. Anyone help to me remove this.

I have tried the below script so far:

```
$('#City').val(null).trigger('change');
$('#City').val('')
$("#city").empty()
```

For reference:
[image]

```js
$('select').select2();
```

```css
.select2-container {
  min-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="City">
<option value="None">None</option>
<option id="one" value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Currently your sample throws `"TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function"`, could you fix that first?

Comment: @Tomalak I have fixed the issue. could you please check the issue

Comment: Nope, your snippet still does not run.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$("#City").select2('destroy')` to destroy select2 and then use **replaceWith** to replace it with normal textbox .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').select2();
  $("#City").select2('destroy'); //destroy..plugin
  $("#City").replaceWith("<input type='text' id='City'>") //replace..
})
```

```css
.select2-container {
  min-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="City">
  <option value="None">None</option>
  <option id="one" value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No. I want to remove the entire Select2 dropdown and change it like a normal input box

Comment: normal select-box  then try `$("#City").select2('destroy');` ? Your question is not clear your question title says something else.

Comment: I have updated the screenshot for your reference

Comment: Sorry. it's a dynamic value. I can't able to use `replaceWith`

Comment: *dynamic value* ..what do you mean by that ? please elaborate  and even if you destroy `select2` it will give you normal select-box not input-box so if you need input-box you need to replace that .

Comment: @Saravana: Why can't you use replaceWith, is the id is also dynamic ?? @ swati we can directly use replaceWith instead of calling destroy 1st

Comment: @Satindersingh because select2 plugin creates its own htmls ..so even if you simply replace select-box that dynamically generated html are still present .

Comment: I think I can't able to clear the Select2 dropdown without using replace or any other default script. Anyway thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$("#City option[value='2']").remove();

$("#City option[value='1']").remove();
```

Comment: I am getting dynamic values for my project. this answer is not helpful.

Comment: $(`#City option[value='${value}']`).remove();